# Saving belongsToMany associations in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, model, save, associations

I have encountered a problem whilst saving belongsToMany associations and the data being saved is a combination of existing entities and new entities.

The data array is as follows:

```
$data = [
    'tags' => [
        ['label' => 'Some new tag'],
        ['label' => 'Another new tag'],
        '_ids' => [1, 2] 
    ]
];
```

Is it that these two methods of saving this association cannot be used together?

I have tried creating a data array where each entity is its own array item like the following:

```
$data = [
    'tags' => [
        ['label' => 'Some new tag'],
        ['label' => 'Another new tag'],
        ['id' => 1], 
        ['id' => 2] 
    ]
];
```

But when it is just ids this does not create new associations. Do I need to handle the creation of new entities first and then create the associations using the ['_ids'] methods, or is there something wrong with my data array?

Comment: can you show you .ctp form ?

Comment: I compile the data array in the table because its not a straight forward form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seconds $data array structure is now possible as of this commit https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/0333639025780d2400b1888d0a2d1cab6c76d37a.